# 1-2-3 Ending Puzzle

Tags: missing-digits

$ED \quad \ \ \ EN \quad \ \  UE$

$451\ \ \ \quad 662\ \ \quad8w3$

$1601\quad2062\quad16x3$

$2551\quad2282\quad16y3$

$2551\quad1112\quad10z3$

There's only one possible value apiece for $w, x, y$ and $z$, tell why and what are they.

### Hint 1

> Give dear maths some holidays

### Hint 2

> All of you have already seen it

### Hint 3

> There are useless digits

### Hint 4 - 20th of July '19

> Extending hint 3, there are exactly twelve useless digits on this puzzle

Comment: I'm not sure about my English right now (I'm French and an English learner) does my formulation means that there are 4 digits, possibly different but unique for $w, x, y, z$ or does it mean there is 1 digit that fits for both $w, x, y, z$? The latter is clearly not what I want to express.

Comment: In light of your comment above, I've suggested an edit to clarify.

Comment: @msh210 Thank you for teaching me some vocabulary haha ;)

Comment: Should we know what is the meaning of ED, EN, and UE or is it part of the puzzle?

Comment: @Moti Good question, it's a part of the puzzle, guessing what does it mean makes it much easier.

Comment: Is the question asked aims at *why* part or also it needs *what* part and asks for values of w,x,y and z? (-_-)

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay I edited my question aiming to clarify, accordingly to your comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "useless digits" of hints 3 and 4 are

> the 1,2,3 on the end, which serve only as indices.

The columns are really labelled

> RED, GREEN, and BLUE.

The missing digits are

> 4, 6, 3, and 5 respectively.

The rows are

> the colours of the text, green region, yellow region, and red region, respectively, of the PSE logo.

I confess I'm not sure I understand hint 1; perhaps it's

> just indicating that despite all the numbers this isn't actually a mathematical question?

Comment: You are right about hint 1. I thought without knowing there are useless digits, it could have been easy to seek pointlessly for hours into mathematical formulas